# 重要ないくつか what is this word ending?

Tags: word-usage

重要ないくつか

I came across this and was wondering what it meant. One can parse it this way:
重要ない ___くつか
Or
重要な  ___ いくつか
Which does makes more sense? And can you give example sentences?

Answer (score 1):

This いくつか is a pronoun, "several ones" or "some". Since it's a pronoun, it refers to something that has been mentioned in the previous context. It's 幾つか in kanji. Jisho.org's entry is [this](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B9%BE%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B), although it doesn't explain the usage as a pronoun. Examples:

- いくつかは赤く、いくつかは白い。
  Some are red and some are white.
- 重要ないくつか
  Some important ones/items/points/aspects/etc
- リストのうち重要ないくつかをピックアップしました。
  I've picked up some important ones in the list.

Comment: Thanks! One of the quirks of longer sentences, in my mind,  is it is sometimes difficult to decide on the morphology of a string of characters.